# Pyecharts: How to save pyecharts as png?

Tags: python, charts

I would like like to save pyecharts figures. Here is my code:

```
from pyecharts.charts import Bar
from pyecharts import options as opts
from pyecharts.globals import ThemeType
bar = (
 Bar()
 .add_xaxis(['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC'])
 .add_yaxis("Temperature Max", [-7,-6,-2,4,10,15,18,17,13,7,2,-3],color="#1565C0")
 .add_yaxis("Temperature Min", [-1,0,5,12,18,24,27,26,21,14,8,2],color='#80CBC4')
 .set_global_opts(title_opts=opts.TitleOpts(title="30-year temperature for Toronto”, subtitle=”Year 1981 to 2010"))
)
bar.render_notebook()
bar.render(path='snapshot.png')
```

It save my file as snapshot.png. However when I open the image it shows following output:
[image]

Comment: Try this: [Python-pyecharts: directly save the picture as a png, pdf, gif format file](https://blog.fearcat.in/a?ID=01800-cf1e188d-84ed-43d4-bd1a-0064d0631002)

Answer (score 0):

[Rendering to images using pyecharts has always been a feature of interest to developers. pyecharts provides selenium, phantomjs and pyppeteer in three ways.](https://pyecharts.org/#/en-us/render_images)

1. selenium

```bash
pip install snapshot-selenium
```

```py
from pyecharts import options as opts
from pyecharts.charts import Bar
from pyecharts.render import make_snapshot

from snapshot_selenium import snapshot

def bar_chart() -> Bar:
    c = (
        Bar()
        .add_xaxis(["衬衫", "毛衣", "领带", "裤子", "风衣", "高跟鞋", "袜子"])
        .add_yaxis("商家A", [114, 55, 27, 101, 125, 27, 105])
        .add_yaxis("商家B", [57, 134, 137, 129, 145, 60, 49])
        .reversal_axis()
        .set_series_opts(label_opts=opts.LabelOpts(position="right"))
        .set_global_opts(title_opts=opts.TitleOpts(title="Bar-测试渲染图片"))
    )
    return c

make_snapshot(snapshot, bar_chart().render(), "bar0.png")
```

2. phantomjs

```bash
pip install snapshot-phantomjs
```

```py
from pyecharts import options as opts
from pyecharts.charts import Bar
from pyecharts.render import make_snapshot

from snapshot_phantomjs import snapshot

def bar_chart() -> Bar:
    c = (
        Bar()
        .add_xaxis(["衬衫", "毛衣", "领带", "裤子", "风衣", "高跟鞋", "袜子"])
        .add_yaxis("商家A", [114, 55, 27, 101, 125, 27, 105])
        .add_yaxis("商家B", [57, 134, 137, 129, 145, 60, 49])
        .reversal_axis()
        .set_series_opts(label_opts=opts.LabelOpts(position="right"))
        .set_global_opts(title_opts=opts.TitleOpts(title="Bar-测试渲染图片"))
    )
    return c

make_snapshot(snapshot, bar_chart().render(), "bar0.png")
```

3. pyppeteer

```bash
pip install snapshot-pyppeteer

# then, you need install chromium
pyppeteer-install
```

```py
from snapshot_pyppeteer import snapshot

from pyecharts.charts import Bar
from pyecharts.faker import Faker
from pyecharts import options as opts
from pyecharts.render import make_snapshot


def bar_base() -> Bar:
    c = (
        Bar()
        .add_xaxis(Faker.choose())
        .add_yaxis("商家A", Faker.values())
        .add_yaxis("商家B", Faker.values())
        .set_global_opts(title_opts=opts.TitleOpts(title="Bar-基本示例", subtitle="我是副标题"))
    )
    make_snapshot(snapshot, c.render(), "bar.png")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar_base()
```